# Azure IOTHUB error Can't create session when the connection is closing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I have python azure function which is read the data from azure IotHub based on the Iothub event trigger.
Below is my code

```
def main(events: List[func.EventHubEvent]):
    try:
        keyfunc = lambda x: (x.iothub_metadata['connection-device-id'])
        data = sorted(events, key=keyfunc)
        for k,v in itertools.groupby(data,keyfunc):
            dictionarylist = [dict(dic, deviceid=k) for dic in [json.loads(x.get_body().decode('utf-8')) for x in v]]
            insertdata(deviceid=k,datalist=dictionarylist)
            insertforprocessing(deviceid=k,datalist=dictionarylist)
    except Exception as e:
           print(e)
```

I continuously got below error and not processing the data. i don't know how to fix this issue.

> fail: Host.Triggers.EventHub[0]
> Error processing event from Partition Id: '3', Owner: 'd5cec505-7f60-4953-9e7a-89323b0fccd2', EventHubPath: 'test-iothub-poulcs4smtna'
> System.InvalidOperationException: Can't create session when the connection is closing.
> at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpConnection.AddSession(AmqpSession session, Nullable`1 channel) at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpCbsLink.OpenCbsRequestResponseLinkAsyncResult.GetAsyncSteps()+MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result) at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpCbsLink.EndCreateCbsLink(IAsyncResult result) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.OnCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
> at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout) at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
> at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.TaskHelpers.EndAsyncResult(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
> at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result) at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.AmqpCbsLink.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<SendTokenAsync>b__1(IAsyncResult a) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpPartitionReceiver.CreateLinkAsync(TimeSpan timeout) at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1.OnCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
> at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout) at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.GetOrCreateAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
> at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpPartitionReceiver.OnReceiveAsync(Int32 maxMessageCount, TimeSpan waitTime)
> at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpPartitionReceiver.OnReceiveAsync(Int32 maxMessageCount, TimeSpan waitTime)
> at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.PartitionReceiver.ReceiveAsync(Int32 maxMessageCount, TimeSpan waitTime)
> at Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Amqp.AmqpPartitionReceiver.ReceivePumpAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean invokeWhenNoEvents)

Comment: i have similar issue

Comment: May I know which version of EventHub are you using?  This issue was seen for the users who are using lower versions and it was fixed in 4.3.0 and higher versions as per this release notes - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs_4.3.1/sdk/eventhub/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs/CHANGELOG.md.